# Displaying bound list of svg files

Tags: wpf, xaml, svg, data-binding, sharpvectors

In my WPF application I have a grid with a fixed set of SVG Images (I use SharpVectors library)

```
<Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="{svgc:SvgImage Source=Resources/0.svg}" Stretch="Fill"/>
<Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Source="{svgc:SvgImage Source=/Resources/1.svg}" Stretch="Fill"/>
<Image Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Source="{svgc:SvgImage Source=Resources/2.svg}" Stretch="Fill"/>
<Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Source="{svgc:SvgImage Source=/Resources/3.svg}" Stretch="Fill"/>
```

Now I want to have item control where I would bind a list of paths to the SVGs, something like this:

```
<ItemsControl DataContext="{Binding DataContext}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Stretch="Fill" Width="100" Height="100">
                <Image.Source>
                    <renderers:SvgImageSource/> <!-- What should be used here as a path??? -->
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But I don't get it how to use string path in the `renderers:SvgImageSource` tag.

Comment: What is SvgImageSource? SharpVectors only seems to have a SvgImageExtension class, which is a MarkupExtension.

Comment: As a note, `DataContext="{Binding DataContext}"` is entirely redundant.

Comment: @Clemens yeah, thanks, removed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an `ItemsSource` for your SVG image URIs. Then you can use the `SvgImageConverter` for binding.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourSvgUriItems}">
   <ItemsControl.Resources>
      <svgc:SvgImageConverter x:Key="SvgImageConverter"/>
   </ItemsControl.Resources>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Image Stretch="Fill" Width="100" Height="100"
                Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource SvgImageConverter}}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to bind to the path and use the [SvgImageConverterExtension](https://github.com/ElinamLLC/SharpVectors/blob/ff1bfec5774f7db6e1673c03deed2d003f22b546/Source/SharpVectorConvertersWpf/SvgImageConverterExtension.cs) class:

```
<Image Stretch="Fill" Width="100" Height="100">
    <Image.Source>
        <Binding Path="YourUriProperty">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <converters:SvgImageConverterExtension />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```